# Im trying to sort an Array Alphabetically. When i run the program it never swaps the names. What do i need to do to fix my program?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

This is my constructor of the user importing a list of their choosing of the amount of names and then it is supposed to sort the names alphabetically, but it doesn't.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyArrayList
{
    public ArrayList<String> getFilledList()
    {
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How man names would you like to input?");
    int num = name.nextInt();

    for(int x=0; x < num; x++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name number of name"+x);
        String bob = name.next();
        array.add(bob);
    }
    return array;
}

public void displayList(ArrayList<String> List)
{
    for(int x=0; x<List.size(); x++)
    {
        System.out.println(List.get(x));
    }
}

public int findFirstAlpha(ArrayList<String> array, int start) //finds the first alphabetical name in the list
{
    int Lowloc =start;
    for(int x=start; x<array.size(); x++)
    {
        if(array.get(x).compareTo(array.get(Lowloc)) > 0)
        {   
            Lowloc=x;
        }
    }
    return Lowloc;
}

public void swap(ArrayList<String> array, int from, int to) 
{
    String devo = array.get(to);
    array.set(to, array.get(from));
    array.set(from, devo);
}

public void SortAlpha(ArrayList<String> array) // sorts the list alphabetically
{
    for(int x=0;x<array.size();x++)
    {
        int loc = findFirstAlpha(array, x);
        swap(array,x,loc);
    }
}

public void swapSort(ArrayList<String> array) //swaps the sort
{
    for(int x=0;x<array.size();x++)
    {
        for(int w=0;w<array.size()-1;w++)
        {
            if(array.get(w).compareTo(array.get(w+1)) <0)
            {
                swap(array, w, w+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

when I run this through my runner the system doesn't swap the names in the list according to alphabetical order it just leaves them in the same order as the user(me) puts them in as.

Comment: ArrayList aren't copied, thanks god. It would be way too slow. Java always give the Object's pointer in parameter, the copy occurs only for native types.

Comment: I don't see where you call the sort method in your code. The class ending bracket is way too early, and there's an upper case for the method `SortAlpha` which is a bad practice. Is this the whole code? Because as-this, it won't work. It seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do a simple alphabetic sort, just use the `Collections.sort(List<T> list)` function instead of implementing your own sort method.

**Example code:**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("cat");
list.add("dog");
list.add("ant");

// Print the original list
System.out.println("Before sort: " + list);

// Sort the list and print
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println("After sort: " + list);
```

**Output:**

> Before sort: [cat, dog, ant]
>   After sort: [ant, cat, dog]

Also, there is no need for the `displayList(ArrayList<String> list)` function.  You can simply call `toString()` on the list.

Comment: TreeSet is even more efficient at sorting data while being inserted. But I presumed OP was a student, Collections.sort() is like cheating :)